# Laravel echo with angular 6 webpack error. Echo is not a constructor

Tags: webpack, socket.io, angular6, laravel-echo

I am working with a Laravel backend and Angular 6 as the frontend and I am trying to implement broadcasting using socket.io.

I have npm installed laravel-echo socket.io. Following the tutorial from the laravel docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting) I am importing the appropriate libraries and attempting to instantiate a new echo instance. This is what that looks like in my app.module.ts:

```
import { Echo } from 'laravel-echo';

declare global {
    interface Window { io: any; }
    interface Window { Echo: any; }
}

window.io = window.io || require('socket.io-client');
window.Echo = window.Echo || new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: 'http://localhost:6001'
});
```

When I then try to compile the application I get this error:

[image]
Uncaught TypeError: laravel_echo__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_32__.Echo is not a constructor

Line 59 referenced is the new Echo... call.
Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this I removed all that I included in the app.module.ts file and included the path to the node module in the scripts array in the angular.json file:

```
"scripts": [
   "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js",
   "node_modules/laravel-echo/dist/echo.js"
],
```

In the component I was then able to reference the Echo object as such:

```
// At the top of the file
declare global {
    interface Window { io: any; }
    interface Window { Echo: any; }
}

declare var Echo: any;

window.io = window.io || require('socket.io-client');
window.Echo = window.Echo || {};
```

Whenever you want to start listening:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: 'https://host-address.com:6001'
});
window.Echo.channel('channel-name')
    .listen('.channelEvent', (data) => {
       console.log('From laravel echo: ', data);
    });
```

Hope this saves someone else some time!

Answer (score 1):

It's not the most beautiful but it works:

**Install dependencies**

```
yarn add laravel-echo
yarn add types/node
```

**Add to tsconfig.json**

```
"types" : ["node"],
```

**Add to app.module.ts**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

(window as any).global = window;
declare var require: any;

declare global {
  interface Window {
    io: any;
  }

  interface Window {
    Echo: any;
  }
}

window.io = window.io || require('socket.io-client');
window.Echo = window.Echo || {};

window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'socket.io',
  host: 'http://localhost:6001'
});

window.Echo.channel('channel-name')
  .listen('.channelEvent', (data) => {
    console.log('From laravel echo: ', data);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem by creating "laravel-echo.d.ts" file in src folder. and declare module in it in the following way.

```
                      declare module 'laravel-echo';
```

and then change the code from

```
       import {Echo} from 'laravel-echo';
```

to

```
       var Echo=require('laravel-echo');
```

problem solved.